# Vector calculations in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vector, angle

I'm making a program that will tell you the angle of limbs when given a picture. So for example, you load a leg splits picture on the screen, you click on each joint, the program records the joints positions, then it gives you the angle between both legs let's say.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015, Windows 10.

I managed to do this on Unity 4.6, but I can't make the vector functions work now on Visual Studio. Basically I found this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.anglebetween(v=vs.110).aspx

... which gives you this method:

```
private Double angleBetweenExample()
{
    Vector vector1 = new Vector(20, 30);
    Vector vector2 = new Vector(45, 70);
    Double angleBetween;

    // angleBetween is approximately equal to 0.9548
    angleBetween = Vector.AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);

    return angleBetween;

}
```

"Vector" doesn't seem to be a proper variable name, so I added using System.Windows.Vector; at the top.
This line gives an error, "Vector" is underlined in red. What am I missing?

Your help is appreciated, and please excuse this basic question, I'm just learning this stuff and I'm quite lost.

Comment: You need to make sure that `WindowsBase.dll` is referenced by your project.

Comment: Not exactly related to your question, but kind of relevant. Note that Visual Studio Express is a restricted version of Visual Studio. With Visual Studio 2015 you have the Community version which is also free, but similar to a conventional (fee-based) Visual Studio. PS: you might easily create your own vector class. Some of the in-built functions might not be so straightforward to be implemented, but perhaps you might not need them. For example: creating a function calculating the angle between two vectors is not too difficult and might be a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Which .net framework are you using?

here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.anglebetween(v=vs.110).aspxit

it is specified to work only for 4.5 & 4.6

Comment: Not true - "Available since 3.0". That page is just the 4.5/4.6 version there are other version of that page.

Comment: "You need to make sure that WindowsBase.dll is referenced by your project. – ChrisF"
This did it, it was very simple, I needed to add the reference and now it works. Thank you guys. I will now check how I have to edit this to display it is solved... can I give points or anything?